# How to use map reduce output as an input for another map reduce job?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In the first map reduce job I am processing an HBase table and outputting a smaller list of the rowkeys. I need to use this list of strings in order to process another map reduce job which is pulling from a different HBase table and outputting to another Hbase table. What is the proper way to store and access the ouput of the first map reduce job?

Comment: If your output from the first MapReduce job is not very large, you can put the output on the Distributed Cache, which will be available to the 2nd MapReduce job to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop doesn't support streaming the output of one MR job to another. So, the output of the first MR job has to be stored in HDFS (or some other persistent storage) and then read in the second MR job. Create a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of jobs using [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) or [Azkaban](http://data.linkedin.com/opensource/azkaban). For a simple work flow use Hadoop's [JobControl](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/JobControl.html) API.

[Apache Tez](http://tez.incubator.apache.org/) which is still in the incubator phase allows streaming of data across MR tasks. As mentioned, Tez is still in the Incubator stage, so use it with a bit of caution.